# Javascript print other page

Tags: javascript, printing, html

I know that I can use `window.print()` to print the current Webpage but is it also possible to print an other page? e.g. `window.print('www.google.com')`

(maybe also using some "hacks")

Comment: You can't do that. Hack: Put the desired page in an iframe, and insert the js there (not a good solution)

Comment: `var w = window.open("www.google.com"); w.print()`

Comment: It was, at least at some point, possible to `window.matchMedia('print')` to react to the print event, but I've never tried if you could still change `window.location` at that point and if that would print the other page. (Not recommended for production use!)

Comment: It might work if both pages have same origin.